# Creating an expandable hash of arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am parsing a file, and every odd line gives me a "letter" (A, B, C, etc), and every even line gives me a "binary sequence" (0101, 1111, 0001, etc).

I would like to create a hash of arrays (but if you think another datatype is more suitable, please let me know) to keep all lines organized.

I know the has of arrays could look like:

```
%HoA = (
    A  => [ "0001", "1010" ],
    B  => [ "0011", "1111", "0111" ],
    C  => [ "0000"],
);
```

and I know how to *access* information from this data type.

However, I am having trouble *creating* this data type.

For instance, I am able to correctly obtain the "letter" ($letter) and "binary sequence" ($seq) for the file, using something like:

```
while (<INPUT>) {
    s/[\n\r]//mg;

    if ( /^>/) {
        $letter = substr($_, 7, 1);
    }
    if ( /^[01]/) {
        $seq = $_;
    }
}
```

But I am unsure how to:

1. create the hash of arrays,
2. check first whether or not that "letter" exists already as a key in the hash
3. if the "letter" does not exist as a key, then how to create it as a new key
4. after either determining the "letter" already exists or creating it if it does not, how to add the "seq" as a value to the "letter".

If such a datatype cannot be created in Perl, then I would appreciate any advice on what sort of data type to turn to! I need to keep each "letter" attached to all its "sequences".

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the hash, just put `my %HoA;` at the beginning of your code.  Given a `$letter` and `$seq`, you can accomplish steps 2-4 at once by just doing `push @{$HoA{$letter}}, $seq;`, and Perl takes care of the details.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your data is infallible.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw/all/;
use Data::Dumper;

$/ = "\r\n";

my %HoA;

while (<DATA>)
{
    my $letter = substr($_, 7, 1);
    chomp(my $seq = <DATA>);

    push @{$HoA{$letter}}, $seq;
}

print Dumper \%HoA;

__DATA__
>      A
0001
>      A
1010
>      B
0011
>      B
1111
>      B
0111
>      C
0000
```

Comment: I really appreciate your advice for Data::Dumper. Thanks for that. I am just curious: What is the meaning of line 6: $/ = "\r\n";

Comment: `$/` is a special variable, the input record separator. It controls which string Perl splits chunks on, while reading from a filehandle. By default it is `\n`, but I noticed you were dealing with carriage returns, therefore set it to `\r\n` as an alternative to your regexp substitution approach. `chomp` will also refer to `$/`.

Answer (score 2):

Check [perl data structures cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS).

```
my %HoA;
my $letter;
while (<INPUT>) {
    s/[\n\r]//g;

    if ( /^>/) {
        $letter = substr($_, 7, 1);
    }
    if ( /^[01]/) {
        #  $seq = $_;
        push @{ $HoA{$letter} }, $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the OP's original question, this is the most useful answer.